# Logstash config-file don't catch my logs, but debugger did

Tags: regex, config, logstash, multiline, elastic-stack

So, I'm a little bit new at the elk-stack, and I’m having an issue with further experiment with the tools. I'm using a linux machine.
First of all, here's my config-file :

```
input {
    file {
        type => "openerp"
        path => "/home/jvc/Documents/log/openerp-cron.log.2014-11-20.txt"
        start_position => "beginning"
        codec => multiline{
                pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} "
                negate => true
                what => previous
        }
    }
}
filter{
    if [type]=="openerp"{
        date{
            match => ["timestamp","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
        }
        grok{
            patterns_dir => "./patterns"
            match => { "message" => "%{ODOOLOG}" }
        }
    }
}
output{
    file{
        path => "/home/jvc/Bureau/testretour.txt"
    }
}
```

I have some patterns too :

```
REQUESTTIMESTAMP %{MONTHDAY}/%{MONTH}/%{YEAR} %{TIME}
REQUEST %{IPORHOST:client} %{USER:ident} %{USER:auth} [%{REQUESTTIMESTAMP:request_timestamp}] "%{WORD:request_type} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}" %{NUMBER:response} -
ODOOMISC %{GREEDYDATA}
ODOOLOG %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{POSINT:pid} %{LOGLEVEL:level} (?:%{USERNAME:user}|\?) %{PROG:module}: (?:%{REQUEST}|%{ODOOMISC:misc})
```

Some examples of the logs :

```
2014-11-21 08:00:16,715 17798 DEBUG noe openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_cron: cron.object.execute('noe', 1, '*', u'crossovered.budget.lines', u'computeblank')
2014-11-21 08:00:17,172 17798 WARNING noe openerp.osv.orm.browse_record.noe_utils.synchro_date: Field 'conform' does not exist in object 'browse_record(noe_utils.synchro_date, 13)'
2014-11-21 08:00:17,172 17798 ERROR noe openerp.sql_db: Programming error: can't adapt type 'browse_record', in query SELECT id
FROM crossovered_budget_lines
WHERE is_blank='t'
AND general_budget_id in %s
AND date_from <= %s AND date_to >= %s
2014-11-21 08:00:17,173 17798 ERROR noe openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_cron: Call of self.pool.get('crossovered.budget.lines').computeblank(cr, uid, *()) failed in Job 10
```

I'm having trouble with this config. For some reason that I can't find, this produces nothing.
What I have tried - done :

-First of all, I tested my grok, and multiline pattern in some grok debugger I have find on the web. All of them matches my logs.

-Before using the codec for multiline, i used the multiline filter. This one worked, but seems to be deprecated. So it's not a solution.

-I know that logstash keep in mind what he had read or not with the "sincedb" files : I delete these before every test, but you know what happens.

-I tried to run logstash with the -verbose, but nothing wrong is displayed.

-I don't really know if I must write the ".txt" at the end of my paths. But anyway, none of them works.

Have I missed something ? Thank you in advance for helping hands.

Answer (score 0):

So, with more test i succeeded. I copied the content of one of my logs file and pasted it in another file : It works.

But, there is now another question : if deleting the "sincedb" file doesn't work, how can i "empty" the cache of logstash ?

Comment: Have restarted logstash after deleting `/root/.sincedb_*` file?

Comment: I don't know what could be the problem but deleting the `$HOME/.sincedb_*` always works for me.

Comment: By the way, are we agreed that closing logstash is making a ctrl+c signal ? And then restarting with "bin/logstash -f name_of_file.conf" ?

Comment: Here i have the answer : You must stop logstash _before_ deleting the files. Hope this will help someone